# How can I reload IPTables without interrupting existing connections?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I will be adding and removing entries to the script below automatically (adding ports 80/443 with different IP addresses). If I run this script, I am "assuming" that connections will be uninterrupted, unless however I remove an IP. Am I correct in this thought?

Here is my script:

```
iptables --flush
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport  80 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods to add new rules to current chains. For example;

- You should write a shell script that reads ip addresses in a file and inserts them to chain.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  for ip in `cat ipadresses.txt`
  do
      iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s $ip -m multiport --dports80,443 -j ACCEPT
  done
  ```
- You should save current rules to a file and add rules directly inside file and restore rules from this file again.

  ```
  /sbin/iptables-save > /path/to/save/iptables.rules
  or
  /sbin/iptables save > /path/to/save/iptables.rules
  ```

  after editing iptables.rules with any text editor you should duplicate any line and change the source ip address.

  ```
   # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Aug 19 00:22:21 2014
  *mangle
  :PREROUTING ACCEPT [9809:4375246]
  :INPUT ACCEPT [9809:4375246]
  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [4718:585599]
  :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4718:585599]
  COMMIT
  # Completed on Tue Aug 19 00:22:21 2014
  # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Aug 19 00:22:21 2014
  *filter
  :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
  -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
  -A INPUT -j DROP
  -A INPUT -j LOG
  -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
  COMMIT
  # Completed on Tue Aug 19 00:22:21 2014
  # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Aug 19 00:22:21 2014
  *nat
  :PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:352]
  :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [70:4526]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [70:4526]
  COMMIT
  # Completed on Tue Aug 19 00:22:21 2014
  ```

After editing file you should restore rules by

```
    iptables-restore < /path/to/save/iptables.rules
```

In conclusion;

- You dont need to flush all rules to add new ip, just insert new rule.
- You have a general drop rule so you dont need to more rules to drop pocket which have 80 and 443 destination ports.
- You dont need to execute iptables -I commands at every turn.